# Is there a way to make a list change size in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to code hangman for a class project, and I'm sure there are easier ways, but  I can't make it look too advanced because I'm still a beginner. I'm trying to break down a word then put it into a list using ljust to make the word big enough to fit in the list, but then I need to remove the spaces from the list and I have no clue how.

Comment: Are you trying to turn a string into a list of characters, or something else?

Comment: Show us some code so that we can help you.

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: Lists are resizable, though that isn't really relevant to the use of `ljust`.

Comment: Python `list` is dynamically expanding and shrinking, so you shouldn't worry about that. If that's you are asking...

Comment: You should provide an example of the starting state and what you want to achieve. In fact, you should try it yourself first and then come back here with some python code

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are asking.  However, it seems like you want to turn a phrase into a list of characters.  The following will turn a string into a list of characters after removing white spaces.

```
answer = "guess this"
answer = answer.ljust(15)
print(answer)
answer = answer.replace(" ", "") # remove spaces
print(answer)
characters = list(answer)
print(characters)
```

You don't need to change the list size in python.  You can add to this list or remove from this list and python will handle the size change.

Comment: every time i try to put in a word thats shorter or longer i get an error